# Returning lists of instances makes no difference? And what about performance?

Tags: python, performance, return

I have just realised that for a specific module in my programme, return or not a list of instances makes no difference at all. With fixed seed the results are identical.

Thus, I would like to know:

1. It seems to be better programming practice to include a return statement. Is that correct?
2. And I am mainly worried about  performance. I am having a hard time timing it, because it seems that other things going on in the computer seem to affect results. I get 4 min 3 sec and then I get 5 min without changing a single comma.

See the example below:

There is a large function that is called from another module and passes a lot of lists containing different instance objects:

```
def check_demographics(month, my_agents, families, firms, my_graveyard, year, mortality_men, mortality_women, fertility, state_id):
```

Inside that function I have the following function:

```
def mortal(my_agents, my_graveyard, families, agent, firms):
    my_agents.remove(agent)
    my_graveyard.append(agent)
    families[agent.get_family_id()].death_member(agent)
    if families[agent.get_family_id()].num_members() == 0:
        families[agent.get_family_id()].empty_house()
    if agent.is_employed():
        firms[agent.get_workplace()].obit(agent)
    return my_agents, families, firms, my_graveyard
```

In the case above, I found out the return is optional. It makes no difference to return the lists containing agents, families, etc.

So, I know the example is not reproducible, but the question is related to a general fact.

I am assuming the list is somewhere in the memory.

p.s. I am not a computer scientist, but a researcher trying to do some agent-based modeling. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question? If it is why you dont really need to return the list, it is because all of your operations are in-place operations. Since you are passing in a REFERENCE to your lists, then those in-place operations will be done on the list itself, and the same reference you passed in will be affectd.

Comment: The question is: if it is optional, I don't need the return, right? Secondly, which way is faster (with or without the return). Thanks.

Comment: What is returned by python is a tuple of references to those objects. Compared to the overhead of the entire function, which works via many many more references, that is simply negligible. Whether to have `return` is a matter of what your function is supposed to do; in general, python avoids returning input that is changed inplace to emphasize this. BTW you shouldn't *time* your code, you should *profile* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, not returning anything is faster. In practice, it won't matter and is a useless micro-optimization.

Python does not move around objects, it moves *references* to objects (which are stored in names). If you have a C++ background, think of `return a,b,c` giving back an array of three pointers. The performance overhead for this is negligible compared to all the other, explicit operations your function is doing.

If you are worried about performance, you should also not time your program. Either *profile* your program to find out where in your program *considerable* time is spent. Or *time* test code to find out how to do critical code (identified via profiling) better. A starting point are the `timeit` package for timing code, and the various python profilers such as `vmprof`.

For example, to find out the overhead of `return` in general, you may time that explicit statement:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'def foo():' -s '  pass' 'foo()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0994 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'def foo():' -s '  return' 'foo()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0981 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'def foo():' -s '  return 1, 2' 'foo()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0961 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'bar, foo=object(), object()' -s 'def foo():' -s '  return foo, bar' 'foo()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.136 usec per loop
```

Whether your do not return, return nothing (an implicit `None`) or return constants doesn't really matter. If you actually return objects, that adds about 0.04 usec (!!!) of overhead. Just *calling* a function is already is already 2.5 times as expensive for performance.

From a standpoint of coding style, IMO the view of python's standard library is best: if something is changed in-place, do not return it. This underlines that objects are changed via side-effects and there is no point to creating a new reference to them.