# How to interpret the results of profiling?

Tags: python, performance, profile

I am not a computer scientist and I have been having a hard time trying to make my agent-based model reasonably fast ([Implementing Pool on a for loop with a lot of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212265/implementing-pool-on-a-for-loop-with-a-lot-of-inputs), [Multiprocessing pool example (parallel) is slower than sequential. Trying to understand pool in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165552/multiprocessing-pool-example-parallel-is-slower-than-sequential-trying-to-und), [Returning lists of instances makes no difference? And what about performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204284/returning-lists-of-instances-makes-no-difference-and-what-about-performance))

Everybody keeps telling me to profile. I gave it another shot, but I have no idea how to interpret the results (using `timeit` I know which function is slower, but I could not use `Pool` or `@jit`).

So given the results below, how should I proceed?
Thanks a bunch.

```
98008290 function calls (96393650 primitive calls) in 568.193 seconds
Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-0>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-10>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-11>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-1>:1(<module>)
    6    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.001 <decorator-gen-1>:1(non_reentrant)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-2>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-3>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-4>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-5>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-6>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-7>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-8>:1(<module>)
    3    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.001 <decorator-gen-8>:1(_held_figure)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <decorator-gen-9>:1(<module>)
 1416    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1000(__init__)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1003(module_repr)
 1245    0.034    0.000    0.166    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1019(init_module_attrs)
 1245    0.011    0.000    0.209    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1099(create)
 1245/32    0.008    0.000   23.613    0.738 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1122(_exec)
 169/105    0.003    0.000    4.104    0.039 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1156(_load_backward_compatible)
 1414/32    0.034    0.000   23.620    0.738 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1186(_load_unlocked)
   15    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1223(_fix_up_module)
 1650    0.002    0.000    0.006    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1266(find_spec)
   19    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1287(load_module)
 1245    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:129(_new_module)
   19    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1311(is_package)
 1631    0.004    0.000    0.009    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1336(find_spec)
 1631    0.022    0.000    0.254    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1401(_open_registry)
 1631    0.034    0.000    0.307    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1408(_search_registry)
  139    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:141(__init__)
 1631    0.006    0.000    0.314    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1423(find_spec)
  139    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:144(__enter__)
  1245/32    0.022    0.000   23.612    0.738 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1465(exec_module)
  139    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:147(__exit__)
  556    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:148(<genexpr>)
 1245    0.055    0.000    2.437    0.002 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1534(get_code)
 1245    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1591(__init__)
 1245    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1616(get_filename)
 1245    0.941    0.001    1.037    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1621(get_data)
 1245    0.011    0.000    0.384    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1631(path_stats)
  120    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1697(__init__)
  120/92    0.004    0.000    4.087    0.044 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1708(load_module)
 1888    0.017    0.000    0.066    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:172(__init__)
  120    0.001    0.000    0.006    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1726(is_package)
  240    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1729(<genexpr>)
  181    0.058    0.000    0.128    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1853(_path_hooks)
 2614    0.012    0.000    0.142    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1870(_path_importer_cache)
  135    0.002    0.000    0.461    0.003 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1887(_legacy_get_spec)
 1631    0.035    0.000    2.252    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1902(_get_spec)
 2857    0.033    0.000    0.035    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:192(acquire)
 1631    0.009    0.000    2.261    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1934(find_spec)
  179    0.006    0.000    0.012    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1979(__init__)
 1253    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1985(<genexpr>)
 1365    0.016    0.000    0.055    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2011(_get_spec)
 2335    0.118    0.000    1.603    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2016(find_spec)
  178    0.016    0.000    0.100    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2061(_fill_cache)
  178    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2090(<setcomp>)
  179    0.002    0.000    0.071    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2102(path_hook_for_FileFinder)
 7719    0.012    0.000    0.017    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2120(__enter__)
 7719    0.013    0.000    0.020    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2124(__exit__)
 1176    0.007    0.000    0.019    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2138(_find_spec_legacy)
1650/1648    0.097    0.000    2.739    0.002 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2147(_find_spec)
 2857    0.031    0.000    0.033    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:217(release)
  216    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2187(_sanity_check)
 1730/92    0.045    0.000   23.736    0.258 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2207(_find_and_load_unlocked)
 1730/92    0.057    0.000   23.753    0.258 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2234(_find_and_load)
 216/214    0.004    0.000    0.051    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2240(_gcd_import)
338220/334774    1.206    0.000   10.385    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2264(_handle_fromlist)
108/107    0.001    0.000    0.052    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2322(__import__)
 1730    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:257(__init__)
 1730    0.017    0.000    0.134    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:261(__enter__)
 1730    0.007    0.000    0.033    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:268(__exit__)
 2857    0.040    0.000    0.106    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:274(_get_module_lock)
 1888    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:288(cb)
 1127    0.011    0.000    0.044    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:293(_lock_unlock_module)
 2335    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:30(_relax_case)
 1804/32    0.007    0.000   23.649    0.739 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:313(_call_with_frames_removed)
 2490    0.035    0.000    0.140    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:437(cache_from_source)
 2490    0.008    0.000    0.014    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:45(_r_long)
 9163    0.047    0.000    0.132    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:50(_path_join)
 9990    0.024    0.000    0.024    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:518(_verbose_message)
 9163    0.050    0.000    0.071    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:52(<listcomp>)
 1365/1155    0.007    0.000    4.094    0.004 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:534(_check_name_wrapper)
   38    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:546(_requires_builtin_wrapper)
 2618    0.042    0.000    0.063    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:56(_path_split)
 1245    0.055    0.000    0.070    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:599(_validate_bytecode_header)
 1245    0.017    0.000    0.823    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:654(_compile_bytecode)
 5307    0.020    0.000    1.598    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:68(_path_stat)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:690(_module_repr)
 1245    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:728(__init__)
 1245    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:732(__enter__)
 1245    0.017    0.000    0.032    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:739(__exit__)
 4980    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:742(<genexpr>)
 1727    0.014    0.000    0.597    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:78(_path_is_mode_type)
 1801    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:790(__init__)
 2490    0.017    0.000    0.104    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:824(cached)
 1245    0.008    0.000    0.010    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:842(parent)
 1247    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:850(has_location)
49/48    0.001    0.000    0.464    0.010 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:859(spec_from_loader)
 1547    0.006    0.000    0.547    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:87(_path_isfile)
 1395    0.020    0.000    0.487    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:884(spec_from_file_location)
  180    0.001    0.000    0.057    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:92(_path_isdir)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(error)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:11(com_error)
  313    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 <string>:12(__new__)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:2(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:2(__init__)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:2(_parse_args)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(AndersonResult)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(Anderson_ksampResult)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(AnsariResult)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(ArgInfo)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(ArgSpec)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(Arguments)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(ArrayFormula)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(Attribute)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(BartlettResult)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(BinnedStatistic2dResult)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(FlignerResult)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(Formula)
    1    0.002    0.002    0.002    0.002 <string>:5(FriedmanchisquareResult)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(FullArgSpec)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(FunctionAttributes)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:5(HistogramResult)
19424    2.346    0.000    2.346    0.000 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis1_object_object}
82904    0.318    0.000    0.318    0.000 {pandas.index.get_value_at}
  199    0.051    0.000    0.051    0.000 {pandas.lib.clean_index_list}
   57    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {pandas.lib.get_blkno_indexers}
 2918    0.095    0.000    0.095    0.000 {pandas.lib.infer_dtype}
   38    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {pandas.lib.is_bool_array}
   76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {pandas.lib.is_bool}
166001    0.169    0.000    0.169    0.000 {pandas.lib.is_float}
249112    0.215    0.000    0.215    0.000 {pandas.lib.is_integer}
   20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {pandas.lib.is_timedelta_array}
   38    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {pandas.lib.isnullobj}
414822    1.023    0.000    1.023    0.000 {pandas.lib.isscalar}
   11    0.054    0.005    0.054    0.005 {pandas.lib.maybe_convert_numeric}
   56    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {pandas.lib.maybe_convert_objects}
    3    0.000    0.000    0.018    0.006 {pandas.lib.reduce}
   65    0.009    0.000    0.105    0.002 {pandas.lib.scalar_compare}
   28    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {pandas.lib.to_object_array_tuples}
415734    2.533    0.000    4.116    0.000 {pandas.lib.values_from_object}
   20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {pandas.tslib.is_timestamp_array}
   48    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {reduce.nansum}
```

Comment: Is this all? Does the code use multiprocessing or something that could be "out of reach" of the profiler? I would have thought that the sum of "tottime" should be roughly the same as the total time (568.193) which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: `ncalls` tells you how often the function was called, `tottime` the total time spend in that function. You'll want to mostly ignore all the built-in decorator and importlib calls, since you probably can't do much about them in the first place, and because they're not taking up much resources in the end anyway. Look at functions with the highest call count and highest total time, and you know where your program spends all its time. Now try to reduce that time and/or call count.

Comment: @deceze It looks like the total time spent in the function calls is at most 2.5 seconds (pandas.lib.values_from_object). So even if you delete that function call shouldn't that speed up the application at most 2.5 seconds? Compared to the total time of ~10 minutes that doesn't seem to do that much? Where does the program spend so much time, or do I misread the output?

Comment: Yeah, as far as this profile goes (which seems like it's missing some things) your program is fine- less than a thousandth of a second for most functions, total time in functions is low even for thousands of calls- hell, `_handle_fromlist` from is running 338,000 times (only 4000 of which are not recursive) and in total spends 10 seconds between itself and things it calls.

Comment: Yes @syntonym, these are the full results. No, after all, I could not implement `multiprocessing`. @deceze, the number of the functions are not in the results... are they? I cannot see for example the function check_demographics() which I know to be the one that is taking the longest in each loop (out of 240).

Comment: How did you profile the program?

Comment: `python -m cProfile main.py`

Comment: This seem to be taking the longest: `415734 2.533 0.000 4.116 0.000 {pandas.lib.values_from_object}` Probably is when I read data from `pandas DataFrame` in order to make probailistic decisions. Should I change for txt and abandon `pandas` for example?

Comment: If I read that correctly it only needs 4 seconds total. So that should not be your problem. Can you save the profiling information to a file via `python -m cProfile -o outputfile main.py` to see if maybe your terminal cut some information there? If you say that you defined a function that does not appear I guess there is something wrong.

Comment: Indeed. Reading the results with `pstats` I realize the output is enormous! Even more difficult to make sense of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use some of the tools available to analyze/visualize the cProfile output like [pstats](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) or [RunShakeRun](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RunSnakeRun)

Answer (score 5):

I would also recommend [flamegraphs](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph/) for interpreting profiling results. It works especially well with [PyFlame](https://github.com/uber/pyflame), which is a PTracing profiler (it has minimal overhead).

A flamegraph looks like this:
[image]